# Can anyone say what is the mistake here I want to connect to the paired bluetooth device using flutter_bluetooth_serial

Tags: android, flutter, dart

exception getting ===>   PlatformException(connect_error, read failed, socket might closed or timeout, read ret: -1, java.io.IOException: read failed, socket might closed or timeout, read ret: -1

Comment: connect method code:     connect method 
  void _connect() async {
  print('connect working');
  setState(() {
  isButtonUnavailable = true;
  });
 if (device == null) {
  show('No device selected');
  print('Device == null');
 } else {
  if (!isConnected) {  await BluetoothConnection.toAddress(device.address).then((_connection) {
              print('Connected to the device');
              connection = _connection;
              setState(() {
                _connected = true;
              });

Comment: connection.input.listen(null).onDone(() {
     if (isDisconnecting) {
        print('Disconnecting locally!');
      } else {
      print('Disconnected remotely!');
         }
            if (this.mounted) {
              setState(() {});
            }
          });
        }).catchError((error) {
          print('Cannot connect, exception occurred');
          print(error);
        });
        show('Device connected');

        setState(() => _isButtonUnavailable = false);
      }
    }
  }

Comment: Have you already solved this problem?